# Quick mod_rewrite help on GoDaddy 

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This htaccess works fine locally, but on GoDaddy the URL isn't caught by the rewrite engine.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^products/amsoil/(.*)/$ /products.php?amsoil=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This worked until a few days ago. Basically`www.somedomain.com/products/amsoil/this-product/` should forward to `www.somedomain.com/products.php?amsoil=this-product` ....did work, and still works locally however now I just get a 404 error on `www.somedomain.com/products/amsoil/this-product/`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified that the following script works on our current hosting plans:

`RewriteEngine on
     rewritecond %{http_host} ^coolexample.com [nc]
     rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.coolexample.com/$1 [r=301,nc]`

There is a possibility that you are on an older version of our hosting plans. If that is the case, you may want to consider upgrading. Check out http://x.co/Zecq for a how-to on upgrading. There is also a link to the 4GH FAQ. Please review that before upgrading to avoid unwanted surprises.